# Analyze indices that shouldn't exist

Tags: sql-server, index

SQL Server provides ways to analyze indices that should be added to a database, but is there a way to identify indices that shouldn’t exist, or be replaced be better ones in SQL server?

For example:

- Indices that uses a lot of space, cause locking during inserts and
  aren’t well used
- Duplicate, or nearly duplicate indices that could
  be replaced by a single index

Please read carefully before marking as a duplicate of another question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of two different questions. 1. [Unused indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49092/how-to-find-unused-indexes). 2. [Duplicate indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141896/find-and-remove-duplicate-indexes). There are others, too, those are just the first two I found.

Comment: Lol! The difference is *in* the question already, *in bullet points*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzIndex scripts for this exact purpose:

https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/

If you're not familiar with the sp_Blitz family of scripts, they are extremely useful. I've used them as a DBA and they've won me accolades for implementing as a developer.

Here is how I typically use the script:

```
USE [DBATools] --I create a database specifically for hosting scripts, etc.
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @VersionDate datetime

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_BlitzIndex]
        @DatabaseName = N'DBNAME', --whatever your db name is
        @Mode = 4, --tons of useful information
        @VersionDate = @VersionDate OUTPUT

SELECT  @VersionDate as N'@VersionDate'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the queries below to answer your questions in my SQL Server.

```
--Find all unused indices in a database    
SELECT  t.name, i.name, sum(DM.user_seeks) as seeks, sum(dm.user_scans) as scans, sum(dm.user_lookups) as lookups, SUM(dm.user_updates) as updates 
        FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dm
        join sys.tables t 
        on t.object_id = dm.object_id
        join sys.indexes I 
        on i.object_id = dm.object_id
        group by t.name, i.nAME
        having sum(user_seeks) +  sum(user_scans) + sum(user_lookups) = 0 and SUM(user_updates) > 0
        order by updates desc


--This is courtesy of thomaslarock.com **
    /* This script will generate 3 reports that give an overall or high level
    view of the indexes in a particular database. The sections are as follows:
    1.  Lists ALL indexes and constraints along with the key details of each
    2.  Lists any tables with potential Redundant indexes
    3.  Lists any tables with potential Reverse indexes
    */
--  Create a table variable to hold the core index info
DECLARE @AllIndexes TABLE (
 [Table ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Schema] [sysname] NOT NULL,
 [Table Name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
 [Index ID] [int] NULL,
 [Index Name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [Index Type] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
 [Constraint Type] [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
 [Object Type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [AllColName] [nvarchar](2078) NULL,
 [ColName1] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName2] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName3] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName4] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName5] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName6] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName7] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName8] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName9] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [ColName10] [nvarchar](128) NULL
)

--  Load up the table variable with the index information to be used in follow on queries
INSERT INTO @AllIndexes
 ([Table ID],[Schema],[Table Name],[Index ID],[Index Name],[Index Type],[Constraint Type],[Object Type]
 ,[AllColName],[ColName1],[ColName2],[ColName3],[ColName4],[ColName5],[ColName6],[ColName7],[ColName8],
 [ColName9],[ColName10])
SELECT o.[object_id] AS [Table ID] ,u.[name] AS [Schema],o.[name] AS [Table Name],
 i.[index_id] AS [Index ID]
 , CASE i.[name]
 WHEN o.[name] THEN '** Same as Table Name **'
 ELSE i.[name] END AS [Index Name],
 CASE i.[type]
 WHEN 1 THEN 'CLUSTERED'
 WHEN 0 THEN 'HEAP'
 WHEN 2 THEN 'NONCLUSTERED'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'XML'
 ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END AS [Index Type],
 CASE
 WHEN (i.[is_primary_key]) = 1 THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
 WHEN (i.[is_unique]) = 1 THEN 'UNIQUE'
 ELSE '' END AS [Constraint Type],
 CASE
 WHEN (i.[is_unique_constraint]) = 1
 OR (i.[is_primary_key]) = 1
 THEN 'CONSTRAINT'
 WHEN i.[type] = 0 THEN 'HEAP'
 WHEN i.[type] = 3 THEN 'XML INDEX'
 ELSE 'INDEX' END AS [Object Type],
 (SELECT COALESCE(c1.[name],'') FROM [sys].[columns] AS c1 INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] AS ic1
 ON c1.[object_id] = ic1.[object_id] AND c1.[column_id] = ic1.[column_id] AND ic1.[key_ordinal] = 1
 WHERE ic1.[object_id] = i.[object_id] AND ic1.[index_id] = i.[index_id]) +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 2) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],2) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 3) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],3) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 4) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],4) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 5) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],5) END  +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 6) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],6) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 7) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 7) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],8) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],8) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 9) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],9) END +
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 10) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE ', '+INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],10) END  AS [AllColName],
 (SELECT COALESCE(c1.[name],'') FROM [sys].[columns] AS c1 INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] AS ic1
 ON c1.[object_id] = ic1.[object_id] AND c1.[column_id] = ic1.[column_id] AND ic1.[key_ordinal] = 1
 WHERE ic1.[object_id] = i.[object_id] AND ic1.[index_id] = i.[index_id])   AS [ColName1],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 2) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],2) END AS [ColName2],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 3) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],3) END AS [ColName3],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 4) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],4) END AS [ColName4],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 5) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],5) END AS [ColName5],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 6) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],6) END AS [ColName6],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 7) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],7) END AS [ColName7],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],8) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],8) END AS [ColName8],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 9) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],9) END AS [ColName9],
 CASE
 WHEN INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].['+ o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id], 10) IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE INDEX_COL('[' + u.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']', i.[index_id],10) END AS [ColName10]
FROM [sys].[objects] AS o WITH (NOLOCK)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[indexes] AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
 ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
 JOIN [sys].[schemas] AS u WITH (NOLOCK)
 ON o.[schema_id] = u.[schema_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'U' --AND i.[index_id] &lt; 255
 AND o.[name] NOT IN ('dtproperties')
 AND i.[name] NOT LIKE '_WA_Sys_%'

-----------
SELECT 'Listing All Indexes' AS [Comments]

SELECT I.*
 FROM @AllIndexes AS I
 ORDER BY [Table Name]

-----------
SELECT 'Listing Possible Redundant Index keys' AS [Comments]

SELECT DISTINCT I.[Table Name], I.[Index Name] ,I.[Index Type],  I.[Constraint Type], I.[AllColName]
 FROM @AllIndexes AS I
 JOIN @AllIndexes AS I2
 ON I.[Table ID] = I2.[Table ID]
 AND I.[ColName1] = I2.[ColName1]
 AND I.[Index Name] <> I2.[Index Name]
 AND I.[Index Type] <> 'XML'
 ORDER BY I.[Table Name], I.[AllColName]

----------
SELECT 'Listing Possible Reverse Index keys' AS [Comments]

SELECT DISTINCT I.[Table Name], I.[Index Name], I.[Index Type],  I.[Constraint Type], I.[AllColName]
 FROM @AllIndexes AS I
 JOIN @AllIndexes AS I2
 ON I.[Table ID] = I2.[Table ID]
 AND I.[ColName1] = I2.[ColName2]
 AND I.[ColName2] = I2.[ColName1]
 AND I.[Index Name] <> I2.[Index Name]
 AND I.[Index Type] <> 'XML'
```

Disclaimer: Run scripts in test environment before applying to production. Run scripts at your our risk.

HTH